# How to customize range of setRandom?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

Eigen provides facilities to play with Matrices, and vectors (where one dimension is 1). I'm trying to develop a function which fills a vector (`double *array`) with random numbers made by `setRandom`.

```
double *gen_random(int size, double min, double max) {
    double *array = new double[size * sizeof(double)];
    Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>::Map(array, size, 1).setRandom();
    return array;
}
```

The code above does that but random range is [-1:1] as per https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#title35.

How do I change range to i.e. [0:99]?

Answer and comments so far seems to suggest adding a loop to obtain the desired result, like:

```
double *gen_random(int size, double min, double max) {
    double *array = new double[size * sizeof(double)];
    Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>::Map(array, size, 1).setRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        array[i] = (array[i]+1)*50;
    return array;
}
```

Comment: There's *surely* a better way than adding 1 then multiplying by 50?

Comment: @Bathsheba That looks like a pretty good way...

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: The reason my I'm against on first glance is that [-1, +1] is so idiosyncratic.

Comment: How random do you need?

Comment: you could also use srand() to randomize the randomness of the random function. (gosh...thats one  random tongue twister). BTW  srand() is basically seeding the random function. you could do something like srand(time(0)) to get somthing totally random every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete, single line, solution:

```
double *gen_random(int size, double min, double max) {
  double *array = new double[size * sizeof(double)];
  ArrayXd::Map(array,size) = (ArrayXd::Random(size)+1.)*0.5*(max-min) + min;
  return array;
}
```

I'm using `Array` instead of linear-algebra `Vector` or `Matrix` to enable addition with a scalar.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use `min` and `max` instead of `1` and `50`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you should probably just perform arithmetic to get your random values into the desired range (i.e. `+1`, then `* 50`). This is basically what would happen with a different requested range anyway.

Comment: Question updated including my understanding of answer/comments, not sure if that's it.

Comment: I'm quite sure that Eigen provides a way to do that without writing a loop, but yes, that's the gist of it.